# "JavaScript" for loop to list of all even numbers in the array

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need help please. I'm supposed to get these values printed from the loop, but when I run my code I'm not getting all of the even values. What am I doing wrong here?

```
let numbers =[
  469,755,244,245,758,450,302,20,712,71,456,21,398,339,882,848,179,535,940,472,
];
```

Even numbers that should be printed are  `244,758,450,302,20,712,456,398,882,848,940,472`

When I use this

```
let evenNumbers = []
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  if(i % 2 === 0) { evenNumbers.push(numbers[i]); }
}
```

It only prints out `469,244,758,302,712,456,398,882,179,940`

I've been so stuck on this and at this point I don't know why my code is not working. Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: You're checking `i` instead of `numbers[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying `%` on `index` and not the `value`. Change the above to the below :-

```js
let numbers =[ 469,755,244,245,758,450,302,20,712,71,456,21,398,339,882,848,179,535,940,472];
let evenNumbers = [] 
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { if(numbers[i] % 2 === 0) { evenNumbers.push(numbers[i]); } } 

console.log(evenNumbers);
```

Comment: Thank youuuuu!!!!! Aw man I spent a day and half trying to figure this out! Thanks so much, obviously a new developer here lolol. Thanks again, I appreciate it alot.